# Add 3rd party repositories button not in version 1.8.0 Lisboa

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

The available manuals and other help sources all refer to the 'Add 3rd Party Repositories button' in Plugins>Fetch Python Plugins and then the Repositories Tab. My problem is that the installation of QBIS 1.8.0 Lisboa does not have the Add 3rd Party Repositories button where stated.

How do I then add 3rd party repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to load the Faunalia Repository specifically because it has a plugin to handle OS MasterMap data.

I have now received a reply from Saber at Lutraconsulting.

In the latest version of QGIS, the 'Add 3rd Party Plugins' button has been removed.

To add Faunalia repository:
From the main menu, select Plugins > Fetch Python Plugins
A new window will appear. Select Repositories tab, and then click on Add ...
A new window will appear again. For name, type:
Faunalia Repository
and for URL:
http://www.faunalia.it/qgis/plugins.xml

Answer (score 4):

You can still add any repository you know using the "Add ..." button.

Hosting external repositories is now discouraged. Plugin authors should add their plugins to the official repository which will serve as a central hub where users can find plugins and report bugs. Work on a rating system is also on the todo list.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this feature was cancelled in version 1.8, because all plugin-authors should store their plugins into the official repository.

However, you still can download plugins from any location and install them manually