# No get more option in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I have recently installed QGIS and trying to work with it but I don't see this option "Get More" at all. As suggested by some previous source, I also checked whether I am behind a proxy but that isn't the case.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Can you please specify what operating system and QGIS version you are using?

Comment: Also, could you also add some links to the previous sources that you mention?

Comment: Where is "Get more" supposed to be? I found [this Stackoverflow GIS question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72921/no-get-more-in-plugin-manager-in-qgis-2-ubuntu-13-04) that's about the plugin system, it's specific to Linux, but maybe it helps.

Comment: It could be a conflict between the Python 2.7 QGIS uses and another python version on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so it goes as an answer.

Basically, no more 3rd party repositories can be used

[Add 3rd party repositories button not in version 1.8.0 Lisboa](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31490/add-3rd-party-repositories-button-not-in-version-1-8-0-lisboa)

Comment: I think this is a different issue. If you don't have "Get More" available, you can not add any plugin. This is due to missing internet connection, or broken python.